# Client stopps reacting to server's messages

Tags: java, swing, sockets, concurrency, timer

I faced a new problem.
I'm writing a messenger in Java+Swing and I chose that way to make a client's conversation with server:

I have class Running(all the code is for client)
(sever is OK - I checked)

```
public class Running {
private Socket s;
private PrintStream ps;
private BufferedReader br;

public Running(){
try{
    s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8072);
    ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    System.out.println("11");
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("00");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}

public String receiveLine(){
    String ret = "";
    try {
        ret = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}

public void sendLine(String s){
    ps.println(s);
}

public void close(){
    try {
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And in main i make one variable

```
  run = new Running();
```

Then I send this variable everywhere and it seemed to work.
It provides readline or writeline throwgh sockets.
I could register a user, log in or add contact.

I can open a MessageFrame to send messages to my contact.
But when I close it, my programm stopps reacting properly to server's messages.
It reacts only to 30-70% of the messages.
I checked - server is OK.
So the problem is in Running or MessageFrameListener

```
public class MessageFrameListener{
private MessageFrame mf;
private User us;
private Contact cn;
private Timer timer;
private Running run;

public MessageFrameListener(MessageFrame m_f, User u_s, Contact c_n, Running r_n){
    run = r_n;
    mf = m_f;
    us = u_s;
    cn = c_n;
    m_f.addButtonListener(new SButtonListener());
    m_f.addWinListener(new FrameListener());
    timer = new Timer(500,new timerListener());
    timer.start();
}


public class timerListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingWorker<String,Void> sw = new SwingWorker<String,Void>(){
                    public String doInBackground() {
                        String ret = "";
                        ret = run.receiveLine();
                        return ret;
                    }
                    public void done() {
                        String[] results = null;

                            try {
                                results = get().split(" ");
                            } catch (InterruptedException
                                    | ExecutionException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        if("m".equals(results[0])){
                            if("-1".equals(results[2]))
                                mf.addLine2("Error");
                            else{
                                mf.addLine2(results[3]);
                            }
                        }


                    }
                };
                sw.execute();
    }
}

public class SButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String insert = mf.getInput();
            if(!insert.equals("")){
                String infoString = "m "+us.getName()+" "+cn.getName()+" "+insert;
                run.sendLine(infoString);
                mf.addLine(insert);
                mf.refreshInput();
            }
    }
}


public class FrameListener implements WindowListener{

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        timer.stop();
        timer = null;
        mf.close();
    }
```

New information!
I started debugging. My client gets messages from server and gets to this line

```
   mf.addLine2(results[3]);
```

But then nothing happens! Swing doesn't add new line.

The code of addLine2:

```
  public void addLine2(String line){
    //dialogArea.append(line+"\n");

    try { 
        if(line != ""){
            String formLine = us.getName()+" ("+now()+")\n";
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), formLine+line+"\n",st2);
        }

    }   
    catch (BadLocationException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Of course   line!="";
May be it is some Swing problem with threads? And Swing can't deal with my requests?

Vasily.

Comment: 1) split your question to the two - three separated questions 2) search on this forum, I can found here a few very interensting codes about Swing and Socket and with SwingWorker / Runnable#Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey what he is saying is right , that string is going to with /n but it is trying to fetch .

```
in that just try with  **While** condition , that till true get the string .
```

Here is the sample ,

```
try {
        while(true) {

            DataInputStream is = new                      DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
          System.out.println("" +is.readLine());

            line =is.readLine();

        } // end of while
    } catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

Comment: New interesting information about the problem(from debugging) ! See the bottom of my question

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me the issue lies in this line, your PrintStream is not set to flush automatically, hence try to change this line :

```
ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
```

to this

```
ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(), true);
```

so instead of storing the input to the buffer, it will flush it out automatically. For more info  [PrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

it could be because the readLine method expects the line to end with a \n. try making the server send the message and a \n at the end of it

Comment: Server sends messages outputStream.println("some string"); So they seem to end with \n because of println

Comment: try making a little test class with a main like this: for(;;) running.receiveLine()    if it doesn't work, see where the code stops in the client

Comment: It won't help. I can send 2 or 2000 messages in first opening of Message Frame and everything is OK. But when I close it and open second time - I receive only 50% of messages.

Comment: could be an issue with the server. if you can't identify the bug, try using something like wireshark to see if traffic is actually sent by the server, and if the message is exactly what you are expecting

Comment: New interesting information about the problem(from debugging) ! See the bottom of my question